# Find all except one in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to skip one user particular by using `_id` and display all others users, I am trying below code its not working:

```
db.user.find(
    { _id: { $nin: ["5848e9ecaec0f31372816a26"] } },
    { username: 1 }
).pretty()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use ObjectId for _id :

```
db.user.find( { _id: { $nin: [ObjectId("5848e9ecaec0f31372816a26")] } } )
```

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**: Use `$ne` for one user `db.user.find( {_id:{$ne:"5848e9ecaec0f31372816a26"} })` .

Answer (score 2):

I'm serching here for sockets which are defined which means that users is online. So use $nin:

```
const indexUsersHelper = async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            return await db.User.find({ socketId: { $nin: 0 } });
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    };
```